# How to allocate more memory on a windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, stream, .net-6.0

I have a application that plays multiple video feed but it is having an out of memory exception. I am using it as 32-bit app because I am using activeX DLL. Is there a way to configure my application to allocate more memory when running it so I don't encounter this error. I have tried using fewer video feeds and it seems to work fine. My current maximum player is 34. Here is a sample code of my application:

```
foreach(var url in urls)
{
    VideoControl vc = new VideoControl()
    flPanel.Controls.Add(vc);
    vc.Play(url);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does your app run as 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: If you are running into out of memory errors it is likely because you are leaking memory. This is a common problem when dealing with native code wrappers, since they can be less forgiving if you forget to dispose something. When dealing with video you should ideally keep a pool of memory buffers that are reused.

Comment: @KlausGütter it is running on 32-bit because the DLLs are not compatible with 64-bit.

Comment: @JonasH could you elaborate how to implement this or a guide on how to use this practice?

Comment: Which DLLs? You did not mention this in your question.

Comment: Start by finding your memory leak, by using a memory profiler. There are many articles on memory pooling, but it may not be possible depending on the library you are using.